# Php composer openssl error

Tags: php, apache, composer-php, lampp, php-openssl

Before asking, i have to say that I have **tried** every similar question here on stack and elsewhere and failed.

I am unable to use `composer` because of this error:

```
requires ext-openssl * -> the requested PHP extension openssl is missing from your system.
```

I have `xampp` on `ubuntu`.

What I have tried:

- I have uncommented `;extension=php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini` (both cli and normal) - did not work
- Installed openssl through terminal outside of php - did not work
- Check in `phpinfo()` if `openssl` is loaded and activated

[image]

- and few more like runing composer through `php -c /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini composer.phar install` where i get error

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library /usr/include/php5/ext/php_openssl.so - /usr/include/php5/ext/php_openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

- I have tried to change `PATH` in `bashrc`, no success either

What i have found strange is the location of extensions...

In `phpinfo()` extension dir is `/usr/include/php5/ext/` even though I have tried to specify another dir in `php.ini` and of course restart apache and still didnt show in `phpinfo()`.

But in `php-config` command I get that extension dir is /`usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525`

I'm not sure if i have multiple php on system but I tried to look for php.ini files and only 2 came up.

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

Comment: Sounds like you have two different installs of PHP. Probably one from XAMPP (/usr/local) and one from Ubuntu base (/usr). If that's the case, you can edit your PATH to prefer the one you want, or just uninstall the one you don't.

Comment: I tried to look for `php.ini` through `find` command and found one in `cli` and one in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`

Comment: To look which `php.ini` files are used by your cli run `php -i | grep php.ini`.

Comment: have tried running php5enmod openssl from the command line?

Comment: php_openssl.dll is relevant to Windows, not *nix

Comment: @btl php5enmod openssl did not help

Comment: Rollback all the changes you have made in php.ini files and just go through these steps http://tutsnare.com/how-to-install-laravel-on-ubuntu-lamp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer install [LAMP](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu) stack vs. xamp:
it is simple and easy config package ...

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-openssl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

To test your installation, run:

```
  composer
```

with this command not required changed php.ini and etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to understand the proper library files system according to OS. In Windows the shared Library files have the extension of DLL and in Linux the shared Library files have the extension of SO.

Wherever you are doing the changes in PHP.ini file is not doing proper. First of all you have to find the correct location of PHP. Since apache service is running it would be easy task to find the location run:

```
$ httpd -V

Server version: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec 17 2010 11:58:24
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.12, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.12, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

The key line in that output is the `HTTPD_ROOT`. That defines where Apache's `ROOT` directory is to start, `/etc/httpd` in my case. Since we have to find the correct location of `PHP` open `SERVER_CONFIG_FILE` which would be sub-directory 'conf' as in my case.

Search in the file for `env_module` which would disclose the correct location of PHP.

```
<IfModule env_module>
    ....
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "location of PHP"
    SetEnv PHPRC "location of PHP"
    ....
</IfModule env_module>
```

Now open the PHP.ini file do the required changes

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it inits
; default extension directory.
;
extension=php_openssl.so
```

If the problem not resolves then let me know.