# I cannot install php composer in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04

I have this error when I try to install composer:

Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

I followed this steps from my terminal in the Downloads directory:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Just like the website says. What can I do now? I'm using Laravel but I need composer first. I have seen on internet that it's something to do with extensions but I don't know how to it.

Hope someone cal help me with this!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Install Synaptic package manager from the Software Center. Then you can use that to install specific PHP modules, in particular the Open SSL module. I'd recommend using a virtual machine though, like vagrant. Or better yet, use Laravel's Homestead, which is a virtual machine with everything you need to get off the ground with Laravel.

Comment: These might help: [The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249620/the-openssl-extension-is-required-for-ssl-tls-protection), [How to enable PHP's openssl extension to install Composer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18064612/934739), [Composer Warning: openssl extension is missing. How to enable in WAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062055/composer-warning-openssl-extension-is-missing-how-to-enable-in-wamp).

Comment: [Php composer openssl error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756590/php-composer-openssl-error), [How to enable OpenSSL for PHP Cli?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/398950/how-to-enable-openssl-for-php-cli).

Answer (score 27):

```
sudo apt-get install composer
```

... worked for me, and will additionally install all of the dependencies. Or, as @Jonathon mentions above, use the synaptic package manager to install composer.  Note that this will get you the latest stable composer, not the devel version that you get from doing it on the command line from getcomposer.org

Answer (score 5):

Install PHP Composer on Linux machine.

**To run below command to Update your packages:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**To run below command to Install the curl utility:**

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

**To run below command to Download the installer:**

```
sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

**To run below command to Move the composer.phar file:**

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Test composer installed

```
composer
```

[Reference Link](https://www.ionos.com/community/hosting/php/install-and-use-php-composer-on-ubuntu-1604/)

Answer (score 3):

I have installed composer by running few commands for my Ubuntu 16.04 - laravel PHP application server.

Setup in home directory :

```
cd ~
```

Install Curl to get the composer library:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Installing composer:

```
sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Move the composer file to bin path :

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Verify composer installation :

```
composer
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```

Related to this issue https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5510.
Hope it also fixes yours